# What is the benefit of $elemMatch when find filters are ANDed by default

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Learning [MongoDB for node.js](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M101JS/about)

In the 2nd week's chapter under **Array Operators**, here's the `boxOffice` array:

```
boxOffice: [{
    "country": "USA",
    "revenue": 41.3
}, {
    "country": "Australia",
    "revenue": 2.9
}, {
    "country": "UK",
    "revenue": 10.1
}, {
    "country": "Germany",
    "revenue": 4.3
}, {
    "country": "France",
    "revenue": 3.5
}]
```

Here is the query for getting revenue *larger than 15 for UK*

```
db.movieDetails.find({
    boxOffice: {
        $elemMatch: {
            country: "UK",
            revenue: {
                $gt: 15
            }
        }
    }
})
```

The confusion here is that query filters are by default **AND**ed in MongoDB's find queries, which should return documents fulfilling requirement of both `country: "UK"` **AND** `revenue: { $gt: 15 }` with the following query:

```
db.movieDetails.find({
    boxOffice: {
        country: "UK",
        revenue: {
            $gt: 15
        }
    }
})
```

One of the expert said that this is wrong way.

> What is the benefit of `$elemMatch` when find filters are **AND**ed by default?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your second example, the way it's formulated isn't going to search for documents with boxOffice arrays containing country: "UK" and revenue greater than 15.  Instead it's going to look for an exact match of what you've provided for boxOffice, which I don't think is what you intended.  In other words, it will search for a document where boxOffice is equal to:

```
{
    country: "UK",
    revenue: {
        $gt: 15
    }
}
```

(Incidentally, such a document couldn't exist in your collection since you can't start a field name with $.)

Instead you'd formulate that query like this:

```
{
    "boxOffice.country": "UK",
    "boxOffice.revenue": {
        $gt: 15
    }
}
```

And the problem here is that it doesn't require that both conditions be contained within the same array element.  So it would match your example document

```
{
    boxOffice: [{
        "country": "USA",
        "revenue": 41.3
    }, {
        "country": "Australia",
        "revenue": 2.9
    }, {
        "country": "UK",
        "revenue": 10.1
    }, {
        "country": "Germany",
        "revenue": 4.3
    }, {
        "country": "France",
        "revenue": 3.5
    }]
}
```

even though there is no single array element with country : "UK" and revenue greater than 15.

That's where **$elemMatch** comes in.  It allows you to require that both (or many) conditions are met by the same array element.  So it will only return documents (representing movies, I assume) where the UK box office was greater than 15.